# Setting ImageViews without blocking the UI thread by caching Bitmaps

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, imageview, out-of-memory

## Introduction

This is going to be a long one. I spent most of my weekend trying different approaches and am putting this up to hopefully help others with similar issues. I don’t have high hopes to find a perfect solution that solves everything, but maybe someone here can surprise me. :-)

## Context

I have 4 `ImageView` in my Android app representing playing cards. When new cards are dealt, an `Animation` ("*HideAnimation*") shrinks the old cards. Then, 250ms later, `onAnimationEnd`, the image in the `ImageView` is replaced and another `Animation`  ("*ShowAnimation*") enlarges it, which looks like the cards flipping around.
The cards are loaded from .png files in the Android drawable folder.

[image]
This shows two animation styles. One flips through the deck, the other changes directly.

## Issue

My first implementation used `setImageResource` directly in the UI thread:

```
ImageView card = findViewById(R.id.cardA);
[…]
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    […]
    card.setImageResource(R.drawable.deck);
    […]
}
```

This worked, and never crashed, but you could clearly see the delay it caused to decode the resource, with a noticeable lag in the animation.
What I needed, was to decode the resource beforehand, so I could quickly swap the image when it was time, but this is where the pain started, accompanied by the dreadful `OutOfMemoryError` (OOME).

(Side note: Obviously, the first thing was to ensure the image sizes were reasonable, which they are: Their resolution is chosen according to their size on a Full HD device, at 507x720 per image. Because of this, downsampling the image, as per [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) does not apply. Forcing a downsampling noticeably reduces image quality.)

## First attempt - LruCache

The first solution I tried, was using the `LruCache` as described on the Android Developer site: [Caching Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html). It uses a `LinkedHashMap` to keep recently referenced objects. However, this solution had a memory problem:

- Variant 1: I limited the LruCache to 5 bitmaps, since I have to cache exactly 5 bitmaps (one for each card, plus the deck image). This worked fine first, but then caused an `OutOfMemoryError` during “stress testing” (running the animation in fast succession, e.g. spamming the “New cards” button).
- Variant 2: I used the suggested memory limit. However, limiting to 1/8 available memory was only enough to cache a single, maybe two bitmaps, so the lag was still present. Increasing this limit to 1/4 memory gave fluent animations, but occasionally caused OOME during “stress test”.

(Side note: A possible work-around could be to significantly limit the rate at which new cards can be requested. While this would probably reduce the number of OOMEs, since it gives the Garbage Collector more time to run, it doesn’t feel like a fix, but rather a work-around, since the underlying problem, the bitmap allocation, COULD still cause an OOME in other cases.)

## Second attempt – Bitmap array

My next attempt was much simpler. I simply have 5 bitmaps in an array.

```
Bitmap[] cardCache = new Bitmap[5];
```

When the "*HideAnimation*" starts, I start decoding the bitmaps (`cn` being the card number 1-4, 0 for the deck side):

```
public static void prepareBitmapInMemoryCache(final Context context, final int resourceId, final int cn) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap drawable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);
            if(drawable != null) {
                synchronized(cardCache) {
                    cardCache[cn] = drawable;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Then, when it is time to change the image and start the "*ShowAnimation*":

```
card.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromMemoryCache(this, resourceId, cn);
[...]
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromMemoryCache(Context context, int resourceId, int cn) {
    synchronized(cardCache) {
        if(cardCache[cn] != null && !cardCache[cn].isRecycled()) {
            return cardCache[cn];
        }
    }
    return getBitmapFromResources(context, resourceId);
}
```

This also occasionally caused an `OutOfMemoryError` in `decodeResource` during “stress testing”.

(Side note: I also tried caching `Drawable` instead of `Bitmap` with no change.)

So, I started getting creative. When getting the bitmap, I tried ensuring there was enough memory:

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromResources(Context context, int resourceId) {
    int availableMemory = getAvailableMemoryInMB();
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    if(availableMemory > 60) options.inSampleSize = 1;
    else options.inSampleSize = 2;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, options);
}
private static int getAvailableMemoryInMB() {
    final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    final long usedMemInMB = (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / 1048576L;
    final long maxHeapSizeInMB = runtime.maxMemory() / 1048576L;
    final Long availHeapSizeInMB = maxHeapSizeInMB - usedMemInMB;
    return availHeapSizeInMB.intValue();
}
```

And when setting the bitmap, I tried actively calling `recycle` on the old bitmap:

```
public static void setCardImage(ImageView card, Bitmap bitmap) {
    Drawable oldDrawable = card.getDrawable();
    Bitmap oldBitmap = null;
    if(oldDrawable != null && oldDrawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        oldBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) oldDrawable).getBitmap();
    }
    if(drawable != null) card.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    if(oldBitmap != null && oldBitmap != cardCache[0]) oldBitmap.recycle();
}
```

But, alas, the `OutOfMemoryError` still occasionally returned (during “stress test”) and I am ready to give up and simply return to the `setImageResource` solution which I know is stable under all conditions.

If you want to see for yourself, the app is on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.johis.game24) and [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=org.johis.game24). The current version 1.3.1 (16 March 2018) uses the “Bitmap array” solution described above, so you can try to provoke the OOME. Older versions use the `setImageResource` method, which has never crashed. I expect to issue an update tomorrow (19 Mar 2018) reverting to the old, stable method, if I can’t find a better solution.

Comment: "The cards are loaded from .png files in the Android drawable folder." -- if you mean literally `res/drawable/`, that's not helping your cause. That is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, and your image will be upsampled for higher-density devices. "I tried ensuring there was enough memory" -- on Android, OOME rarely is caused by running out of memory, but instead because there is no single block big enough for your ~1.4MB allocation. Allocate your `Bitmap` objects *once*, reusing them via `BitmapFactory.Options` and `inBitmap`, since they are always the same resolution.

Comment: @CommonsWare I had moved the files from `res/drawable-xxxhdpi` to `res/drawable/` earlier to debug some unrelated layout problems and forgotten to move them back. **I moved them to the correct folder again and that definitively helped a lot!** I now can no longer provoke an OOME using my previous methods, so maybe that is even THE solution. Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought about using the `inBitmap` field, however, that would require me to keep references to 4 more `Bitmap` objects (since the 4 next bitmaps are decoded while the 4 old ones are still on-screen). A quick test seems to still return "_Unable to reuse an immutable bitmap as an image decoder target._" using this method.